# Inherited Canon lenses and ring flash — will this work with a new camera body?

Tags: canon, upgrade

Part of my dad's inheritance was a Canon 60D with a fair number of decent macro lenses. Since I've been slack trying to use it (it's been a year) my dear old mum is hinting that she might want it back. In the meantime though I've started enjoying taking pictures. I fitted the 50mm (below) and I had a good old chuckle seeing the images from the camera and the ones I've been taking with my old iPhone side by side.

Not wanting to be a jerk, I'm now considering options because honestly I can afford it, and maybe we can split the lenses or something. What I have here is:

- The Canon EOS 60D
- A Canon 50mm f1.8 EF
- A Zeiss makro-planer 2/50 ZE (I think it's manual)
- An EF-S 17-85 macro lens of some type, I think also Canon
- A Canon 100mm macro lens
- A samyang 14mm f2.8 EF (also manual)
- A ring flash thing.

As for myself, I'm more interested in landscapes and things so I'm hoping to keep the samyang. Would there be any kind of sensible upgrade or replacement that fits some or all of these lenses? Anything full frame, or would that be overkill? What seems like a fair split?

I'm a bit of a noob here and I'd like to do this right.

*Edit*: The question is somewhat tongue-in-cheek. Me and my mum are fine. We're just considering options.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Are you looking for a way to make a financially-even 50/50 split? That doesn't really seem like a photography question — just see what the items are going for used online and split that way. Or are you asking if there is any problem with any of this equipment and current Canon camera bodies?

Comment: I too am not sure I understand what you are asking. Are you going to return the 60D camera body to your mother, buy a body for yourself, and are wondering what's a beneficial way to split the lenses between your mother and yourself?

Comment: @osullic. Yes, this

Comment: @mattdm I'm not sure which of these lenses go with which bodies. In addittion, some will be worth shipping to her, some will not. I'm in Australia, she's in Europe.

Comment: "Worth shipping" is either subjective or else simply something we don't normally cover (because prices change). Is there a reason to suspect that some of these lenses went with a different, non-Canon camera?

Comment: @mattdm I simply don't know. I think they're all for the same camera, but he's had a couple. The question is more; do they still fit current year camera's I guess, if went and bought a new one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between EF and EF-S lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses)

Comment: I think the above should cover that.

Comment: @mattdm having read the answers and googled the terminology, I think yes it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These lenses will work on current camera bodies, keeping in mind the EF vs EF-S distinction as explained at [What is the difference between EF and EF-S lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses). (EF-S corresponds to an APS-C sized sensor, like that in your dad's 60D — see the linked question and some related ones for some Canon-specific details.)

Of the lenses you've listed, the Zeiss manual lens is a treasure — but more suited to a specific style of photography. (And, on EF-S, decent as a portrait lens but kind of awkwardly narrow for a lot of general use. See [Why do people recommend 50mm or other prime lenses as starting lenses for learning photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8939/why-do-people-recommend-50mm-or-other-prime-lenses-as-starting-lenses-for-learni) for some more on that.) The 100mm macro might also be valuable depending on which it is (Canon makes/made several).

I'd suggest looking at used prices on Amazon to get an idea of value, if that comes into the situation with your mother. Or, if it's more about figuring out who will use which lenses more, [What is focal length and how does it affect my photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103/what-is-focal-length-and-how-does-it-affect-my-photos) is probably the best starting point. (Or other questions in the tag [focal-length](/questions/tagged/focal-length).)

Comment: Cheers for the edits

Comment: You might want to note that the Zeiss Makro-Planar 2/50 ZE has a MM of 0.5X or 1:2 reproduction ratio. And as far as Zeiss lenses goes, isn't spectacular optically.

Comment: Yeah, the magnification definitely important if macro is an interest. I haven't used this specific lens but generally I haven't seen anything but praise for the optics.

Answer (score 3):

A short survey of what you've got:

> The Canon EOS 60D

Is an APS-C camera introduced in August 2010 to replace the EOS 50D. It was supplanted by the EOS 70D in July 2013. The 70D has since been replaced by the 80D. But that's not all of the story.

When Canon "replaced" the 50D they did so with two camera models:

- The 60D was the continuation of the 'x0D' line but took a few steps backwards in a few specific areas.
- The brand new 7D, introduced less than a year before the 60D, was a half-step above the 50D and [in some ways was the true successor to the 50D](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/38916/15871).

Even current upper level Rebels/x00D models have better AF systems, frame rate, and just as good or better image quality than the 60D. The 60D does have two control wheels compared to the Rebel/x00D's one (with the sole exception of the T6s/760D that has been replaced by the 77D).

Some of what the 60D "lost" to the 50D was included again in the 70D (AFMA), as well as an more sophisticated and improved AF system. The current 80D has the best sensor Canon has ever put into a APS-C body that beats most previous examples (many of which were based on the same 18MP design) pretty handily in low light/high ISO shooting situations. Even the 7D Mark II, released in 2014, has a sensor that is a step behind the 80D's.

> A Canon 50mm f1.8 EF

The EF 50mm f/1.8, EF 50mm f/1.8 II, or EF 50mm f/1.8 STM? All are budget 50mm prime lenses that are excellent *values* but not necessarily excellent performers for a prime lens. The first and third are preferable to the second, but there is not a lot of difference optically between all three. The EF 50mm f/1.4 is *long* overdue for an update. A great consumer grade 50mm prime is a hole in Canon's current offerings.

> A Zeiss Makro-Planar 2/50 ZE (I think it's manual)

Yes, it is definitely manual focus. In terms of exposure control it is fully compatible with all of Canon's exposure modes.

It is also a better lens optically to the Canon "nifty fifty" series, and the price reflects that. As far as Zeiss lenses go , though, it's on the lower end of the range. With 0.5X (1:2) maximum magnification, some folks don't consider it a "true" macro lens, but a few others do. The  recently discontinued Canon EF 50mm Compact Macro was one of the first EOS lenses introduced way back in 1987. It was similar optically to the Zeiss 50mm Makro-Planar, but comes nowhere close in terms of built quality. For APS-C Canon cameras, the EF-S 60mm f/2.8 Macro is another option to consider.

> An EF-S 17-85 macro lens of some type, I think also Canon

The EF-S 17-85mm f/4-5.6 IS, a 2004 design, was supplanted by the optically better and more reliable EF-S 15-85mm f/3.5-5.6 IS in 2009. Both were 'kit lens' upgrade options offered in place of the more typical 18-55mm for Canon APS-C cameras of their times. Your father probably acquired this lens in a kit with the 60D when he purchased it.

The 17-85 was officially discontinued in 2015 and is probably no longer supported by Canon service centers. If it still is repaired by them, it probably won't be for much longer. The EF 17-85mm had a known issue with ribbon cables cracking with extended use.

It has no macro capability. The minimum focus distance of the EF-S 17-85mm is a little over 12 inches which only gives a maximum magnification of 0.20X or 1:5 at 85mm. "True macro" begins at 1.0X or 1:1, although some folks consider 0.5X or 1:2 macro when used with APS-C cameras that have an enlargement ratio 1.6X that of 35mm film or a FF digital camera to view an image at the same display size.

> A Canon 100mm macro lens

There are two, the EF 100mm f/2.8 Macro and the EF 100mm f/2.8 L IS Macro. Both are similar optically, but the "L" has image stabilization and better build quality/weather resistance. If your macro work is done from a tripod indoors, there's no real reason to prefer the more expensive "L" over the other.

> A Samyang 14mm f2.8 EF (also manual)

Both manual focus and manual aperture control via the aperture ring on the lens rather than through the camera's control system. This means you're pretty much restricted to manual exposure as well as manual focus. A good lens for astrophotography and wide landscape vistas.

> A ring flash thing.

Very useful for macro work, both because the close focus distances make the lens' effective aperture narrower than its nominal f-number measured when the lens is focused at infinity as well as because the lens is often so close to the subject that it blocks a significant portion of the ambient light that could potentially illuminate the subject.

> Inherited Canon lenses and ring flash — will this work with a new camera body?

Everything on your list, other than the EF-S 17-85mm, will work with any Canon EOS film SLR or DSLR. The EF-S 17-85mm is an APS-C only lens and will work with any Canon EOS APS-C DSLR, but not with a FF camera.

Answer (score 1):

Since the lenses all came from your father's collection and fit the body from his same collection, they will be compatible with any equivalent camera with the same mount (namely, crop-frame bodies with EF/EF-S mount). If you are interested in moving to full frame, you will need to determine which lenses have [EF-S mounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF-S_lens_mount) (for crop frame) and which have [EF mounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF_lens_mount) (for full frame).

EF/EF-S lenses will require an adapter to work with cameras that have [EF-M mounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF-M_lens_mount). There are also electronic EF adapters for other camera mounts ([NEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_E-mount), [MFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Four_Thirds_system), [FX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujifilm_X-mount), [GFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujifilm_GFX_50S)) that can control auto focus and image stabilization. There is at least one combination focal-reducer, electronic adapter that gives crop sensors a field of view that is close to full-frame.

EF-S lenses made by Canon can be identified by an extra ring of plastic that prevents them from being mounted on full-frame bodies. However, EF-S lenses made by third parties may still mount on full-frame bodies. In this case, they may be identified by heavy vignetting in the images taken with them. Care should be taken to ensure that lens elements do not obstruct and damage the mirror.

[image: EF-S Mount]
[image: EF Mount]

---

As far as dividing the set, it's really dependent on what your mother wants or needs. The best way to find out is to ask her. Then you can send her the items that best fit what she tells you.

For example, if she just wants a camera to take pictures with, but doesn't like swapping lenses, you can send the body and the 17-85mm lens. If she wants a few extra lenses to expand her options, you can add the 14mm and 100mm. If she's comfortable swapping lenses or working with fixed focal-length lenses, she might like the 14mm, 50mm, and 100mm. However, I would expect that if the latter were the case, she would have her own camera and lenses already.

If she says something vague, like "send what you think is best", then you can either probe more deeply to find out what types of photos she plans to take or just send the set that will provide the most flexibility and ease of use (the body and zoom lens).

As far as *shipping* costs are concerned, you get more bang for your buck by shipping the most expensive items, which are likely the items you'd prefer to keep.You can also wait for a holiday when you would be visiting anyway.

Comment: Thanks. In addition to the "EF EF-S" suggestion I think this should suffice to make an informed decision. If she wants any of these lenses we'll consider the cost of shipping and the cost of replacement. Yes, also the 14mm.